# How to select an option from list after page load in React Js & Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

By using React Js & Material UI **(Using functional Component)**  I need to select an option from a select list, once page is loaded completely, As i need to get the option from URL so once get the option from URL , and after data is being loaded into the select list  i want to select the list as per my option i got from URL

here is my select list

```
SetOption('My Option which i get from URL');
```

`<Select  id="productName"  name="productName" options={jsonProducts} onChange={onSelectChange}    placeholder={"All Products (" + supplierProducts.length + ")"}  ref={productInputRef} />`

here all the Elements in this select list are coming from an API which i am keeping in  `jsonProducts`

so how can i make this select list to select a particular element

Answer (score 0):

There is a value props in React Select:

```
<Select
...
     value = {*state variable with the value you want be to shown*}

...

/>
```

References:

- https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select
- https://react-select.com/props#api

Comment: Is it necessary to have it as state variable , because instead of using state variable i hard code {*state variable with the value you want be to shown*} this part and it didn't work

Comment: I always use a state variable in this circumstances. A state variable can be updated after some needed info is obtained from a server and show the respective value on the Select box.

Comment: where should i write SetOption('My Option which i get from URL'); ,and catch page load , select list load ,   completely to fire SetOption('My Option which i get from URL');

Comment: It depends on where you are declaring the State Variable if you are using React Class components which I do. With hooks is similar... but the key is to find in your code the block that tells you "the needed info is uploaded" and there use a command like setState. Functions can be passed as arguments in React

Answer (score 0):

You can add a value like this

```
value={jsonProduct.filter(option => option.value === YourStateVar)}
```

Your Select list now look like this

```
           <Select  id="productName"   value={jsonProduct.filter(option => option.value === YourStateVar)}   
 name="productName" options={jsonProducts} onChange=
    {onSelectChange}    placeholder={"All Products (" + supplierProducts.length + ")"}  
        ref={productInputRef} />
```